# Representing a color in an Attribute in .NET Standard

Tags: c#, colors, custom-attributes, .net-standard

I'm using .NET Standard 2.0 and I want to create a custom attribute with a color property.

For example:

```
public class DesignAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public ??? BackgroundColor { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that this property should be a constant or a primitive type and be resolved at compilation time.

So its type can't be `System.Drawing.Color` neither an `int` for ARGB representation because

```
public class FooModel
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DesignAttribute(Width = 20, BackgroundColor = Color.Red.ToArgb())]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

gives me a compile error

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type.

I also tried to use a `Byte[]` and fill it with the A, R, G and B properties of my static color class but I get the same error. Even using a `string` and setting it to `Color.Red.Name` doesn't work.

The [`System.Drawing.KnownColor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.knowncolor?view=netcore-2.1) enum would have been perfect, it exists in .NET Framework and .NET Core but not .NET Standard because Xamarin doesn't have it. (See this [Github thread](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/240))

So I'd like to know what are my options in .NET Standard? How can I represent a color as a valid Attribute parameter?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use GDI+ `System.Drawing.Color` or WPF`System.Windows.Media.Color` because as you already noted they're not portable. You can define your own set of constants but it's a tedious job and it's like reinventing the wheel, fortunately WPF itself (and HTML...) gave us a tip:

```
public class DesignAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public string BackgroundColor { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can have:

```
public class FooModel
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DesignAttribute(Width = 20, BackgroundColor = "red"]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Of course you have to support multiple formats (such as `#abcdef`), value can be used as-is (for example when rendering to HTML) or converted to another structure(if, for example, client is WPF or another drawing framework which supports .NET Standard. In the former case it can be (assuming you're targeting .NET Framework in a WPF application) as simple as:

```
var color = (Color)colorConverter.ConvertFromString(attribute.BackgrouncColor);
```

As [you found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51837351/representing-a-color-in-an-attribute-in-net-standard/51837863?noredirect=1#comment90661463_51837863) yourself in <s>.NET Standard</s> the [System.Drawing.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common) Nuget package you have a perfect match:

```
var color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(attribute.BackgroundColor);
```

If you want to avoid magic strings then you may create a simple color list:

```
static class Colors {
    public const string Red = "red";
}
```

This list might even be autogenerated with a simple [T4 transformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb126478.aspx) (see example), list can be obtained with:

```
typeof(Colors).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Select(x => ((Color)x.GetValue(null)).ToString());
```

Note: do not forget to mark your custom attributes with `[Serializable]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I generated an `ArgbConstants` class from all the values in `KnownColor` but I think I will for your solution with the `ColorConverter` class (note that `ConvertFromString` isn't a static method, therefore an instance of `ColorConverter` must be created)

Comment: Actually my question was about .NET Standard.The `ColorConverter` class exists in .NET Framework as well as .NET Core but not in .NET Standard. Instead there is `System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(myStringColor)`. I just tried your solution in my .NET Standard library today and realized that...

Comment: Yes, I suggested `ColorConverter` for when you use the library in a .NET Framework WPF client (otherwise no point to add a dependency to its assemblies even if you're already targeting .NET Framework). I didn't know about `ColorTranslator`, very good catch!

Comment: I found myself very confused today, not remembering exactly where I found this `ColorTranslator` class. It is not yet part of the .NET Standard yet but is included in a Nuget package that can be referenced in a .NET Standard library. I updated your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the compiler error by setting the `BackgroundColor` to a constant.

```
public class FooModel
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DesignAttribute(Width = 20, BackgroundColor = Constants.RedArgb)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static class Constants
{
    public const int RedArgb = -65536;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved using a property in the type itself

```
public class MyClass
{
    [MyAttribute(BackgroundColorPropertyName = nameof(MyPropertyColor))]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }

    public static Color MyPropertyColor {get; set;} = Color.Red;
}
```

Then later pulling out it using

```
(Color)from.GetProperty(attribute.BackgroundColorPropertyName, 
    BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
```